# Setting google maps height to 80% of the screen in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am starting a new Android application, I have used the default template provided by Android studio to create a google maps interface, currently I have set the height to 100dp, but I need it to be 80% of the screen height.

I'm not sure about responsive layouts in Android, I just need some room below the maps to add a new button, but currently the Google maps default template takes up the whole screen.

XML layout:

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/map"

    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" 
    />
```

Comment: you want to do it in java or xml ?

Answer (score 3):

**weight** is the best option to do this-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1"
tools:context="com.mapdemo.deepanshu.MapsActivity" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".80"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".20"
    android:background="#22bfb2"
    android:text="Google Map Demo"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Work for met thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout's `weight` attribute. It works like percentage

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20">

        <!-- Empty view. You can put here whatever you want -->

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting weight to your layouts like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Map -->

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_detail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

    <!-- Button -->

    <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:text="Text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="80" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20">
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```